# latexmk -pv default previewer

Tags: latexmk, sumatrapdf

I currently use Acrobat as my default pdf viewer for everything other than latex related tasks. So not particularly keen on changing my system default.

I would like to get latexmk to use sumatrapdf to open pdf files.

But I can't figure out where to set this option?

Answer (score 7):

From `texdoc latexmk`, you can put the following in `%HOME%/.latexmkrc` if you want this set for anything run by your user, or in `<project-dir>/.latexmkrc` if you want this set on a per-project basis:

```
$pdf_previewer = ’start "c:/Program Files/SumatraPDF (x86)/SumatraPDF.exe" %O %S’;
```

Change the path as appropriate for your installation, of course. The path is quoted because of the spaces in directory names.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering how I would add that to a sublime build file. something like `"-e","\\$pdf_previewer = ’start \"d:/sumatra_portable/SumatraPDF.exe\" %O %S’",`

Comment: BUt dont seem to be getting it to work

Comment: @AndreBeelders your question does not mention anything about Sublime Text. I answered the question you asked. Anyway, whether you call `latexmk` from the command line or from within an editor, the preferences in `.latexmkrc` should be respected all the same.